# How do I send a message to a flask-socketio client outside of request and application context?

Tags: python-2.7, flask, socket.io, flask-socketio

I'm running a python web server, using eventlet for WSGI, with flask and flask-socketio.  A web page is served to the client over HTTPS, and that page uses socketio to start a websocket connection back to the server.

When the socketio connection is established, the client sends a message to the server asking for some state.  The server receives this message, and uses `send(sign_config)` to send a message back to the server.

All of this works.

However, the reason I'm using socketio is that on occasion, state changes on the server side and this needs to be pushed to the client.  I've tried this a number of different ways and all of them fail, but here is what I'm currently trying:

```
with self.app.app_context():
    self.socketio.send(sign_config, room = sid)
```

I'm not sure if the app_context() is needed or not.  I don't get an exception if it's there or not.  Either way, the send function does not generate any exception.  However, the message is not received by the client.  Furthermore, the next socketio ping request to the server fails.  After a short time, the client reestablishes the connection to the server, with a new sid.  In short, sending this message seems to kill the websocket connection, or at least move something out of sync.  I'm certain the sid I'm using is correct.

This is basically the code that actually sets up the environment:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'asdf'
socketio = flask_socketio.SocketIO(app)
socketio.run(app, host = '0.0.0.0', port = 443, certfile = cert_path, keyfile = key_path_result, ssl_version = ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS)
```

The app and socketio objects are being passed to a different class which handles some of this stuff, which is why the code above is self.app and self.socketio.  But they are the same objects.

Does anybody know what might be going on here?

Edit, some other things I've tried:

```
# This produces no exception, but fails to send and breaks websocket connection
with self.app.app_context():
    self.socketio.send(sign_config, namespace = '/', room = sid)

# This produces no exception, but fails to send and breaks websocket connection
with self.app.app_context():
    send(sign_config, namespace = '/', room = sid)

# This produces no exception, but fails to send and breaks websocket connection
self.socketio.send(sign_config, namespace = '/', room = sid)
```

Here are the messages that are sent and received by the server:

```
# The connection is open, and communicating
203786b0b9f54526bd71827a7ba0c4e0: Received packet PING data None
203786b0b9f54526bd71827a7ba0c4e0: Sending packet PONG data None
203786b0b9f54526bd71827a7ba0c4e0: Received packet PING data None
203786b0b9f54526bd71827a7ba0c4e0: Sending packet PONG data None
203786b0b9f54526bd71827a7ba0c4e0: Received packet PING data None
203786b0b9f54526bd71827a7ba0c4e0: Sending packet PONG data None

# Server sends a message to the client with flask_socketio.send(sign_config, namespace = '/', room = sid)
# This message is not received by the client
emitting event "message" to 203786b0b9f54526bd71827a7ba0c4e0 [/]
203786b0b9f54526bd71827a7ba0c4e0: Sending packet MESSAGE data 2["message",{<my message data here>}]

# Client sends a ping
203786b0b9f54526bd71827a7ba0c4e0: Received packet PING data None

# Server sends a pong that is not received by the client
203786b0b9f54526bd71827a7ba0c4e0: Sending packet PONG data None

# Server seems to recognize the client is gone and closes the connection
203786b0b9f54526bd71827a7ba0c4e0: Client is gone, closing socket
203786b0b9f54526bd71827a7ba0c4e0: Client is gone, closing socket

# Client realizes the connection is down and reconnects
(1335) accepted ('192.168.5.1', 52399)
250467e2dd1f439b8724a2338cbc3fb4: Sending packet OPEN data {'pingInterval': 25000, 'pingTimeout': 60000, 'upgrades': [], 'sid': '250467e2dd1f439b8724a2338cbc3fb4'}
250467e2dd1f439b8724a2338cbc3fb4: Sending packet MESSAGE data 0
250467e2dd1f439b8724a2338cbc3fb4: Received request to upgrade to websocket
250467e2dd1f439b8724a2338cbc3fb4: Upgrade to websocket successful

# Client sends a message on successful connection
250467e2dd1f439b8724a2338cbc3fb4: Received packet MESSAGE data 2["message",{<}]
received event "message" from 250467e2dd1f439b8724a2338cbc3fb4 [/]

# Servers sends a message (in request context) in response using flask_socketio.emit('message', data)
# The client receives this message
emitting event "message" to 250467e2dd1f439b8724a2338cbc3fb4 [/]
250467e2dd1f439b8724a2338cbc3fb4: Sending packet MESSAGE data 2["message",{<my message data here>}]

# Connection stays back up until the server sends an out of request context message, where the whole process repeats
250467e2dd1f439b8724a2338cbc3fb4: Received packet PING data None
250467e2dd1f439b8724a2338cbc3fb4: Sending packet PONG data None
250467e2dd1f439b8724a2338cbc3fb4: Received packet PING data None
250467e2dd1f439b8724a2338cbc3fb4: Sending packet PONG data None
250467e2dd1f439b8724a2338cbc3fb4: Received packet PING data None
250467e2dd1f439b8724a2338cbc3fb4: Sending packet PONG data None
```

Answer (score 1):

To send an event without a request context you have to specify both the room and the namespace. If one or both of these are missing, an attempt to get the from the request context will be made, and this is when you get the error.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply.  I'm not getting an error (exception).  The message is just not being received by the client, and the attempted send is breaking the socketio connection.  Before the send, socketio pings go back and forth correctly.  After the send, the next client ping is not returned.  Also, I added some other things I've tried to the end of my post, including adding namespace.

Comment: I don't understand how a send operation can break the connection. You may want to add verbose logs to your server and include those in your questions, that'll help me see more clearly what's happening.

Comment: I've set logger = True on the socketio object, and I now see a message that says "emitting event "message" to f51fbe3b15ef413d8e26caf5e64932d2 [/]".  But Wireshark shows no packet actually being received.  How can I go about turning on more detailed logging than this?  (I could provide spew() results if needed as well.)

Comment: Add `engineio_logger=True` for the lowest level logs.

Comment: Thanks.  I added detailed log data to the end of my post.  The server software seems to be sending the messages without exception, but they aren't being received.

Comment: How do you know the PONG isn't received by the client? And also, how many seconds passed between the last PING received by the server and the "Client is gone" message?

Comment: 33 seconds between the sending pong and the client is gone messages.  I know the pong is not being received by client by watching the chrome websocket messages.  https://i.imgur.com/FvFtJFB.png  You can see the last ping, with no pong response.

Comment: If this all seems inexplicable, know that my server is running a custom linux build (using the Yocto project).  If some strange combination of package versions or something could explain this, it might be a possibility.  It was difficult for me to get all the needed packages working.

Comment: In that image from Chrome, the "2" is the PING and the "3" is the PONG. So I don't understand why you say that pongs are not received by the browser. I really can't explain what's going on. If you are using a non-standard OS, I suggest you test on Ubuntu or other known stable environment.